# Can't figure out why this xpath selector is not working

Tags: python, xpath

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="left-info"> 
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"> 
    <meta content="/store/apps/developer?id=KONAMI" itemprop="url"> 
    <a class="document-subtitle primary" href="/store/apps/developer?id=KONAMI"> 
        <span itemprop="name">KONAMI</span> 
    </a>  
    <a class="document-subtitle category" href="/store/apps/category/GAME_SPORTS"> 
        <span itemprop="genre">Sports</span> 
    </a>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

I've tried a bunch of different xpath selectors but for whatever reason, I can't pick up both the `Sports` and `KONAMI` values. For example:

```
//div[@itemprop="author"]//span[contains(@itemprop,"genre")]//text()
//div[@itemprop="author"]//span[contains(@itemprop,"name")]//text()
```

This gives me `KONAMI` but an empty array instead of `Sports`. I can't figure it out.

I'm using Scrapy to scrape the Google Play Store. The url for the example above is `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.konami.pesam`. Here is the `parse` function:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'utc': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        'store': 'itunes',
        'category': response.selector.xpath('//div[@itemprop="author"]//span[contains(@itemprop,"genre")]//text()').extract(),
        'seller': response.selector.xpath('//div[@itemprop="author"]//span[contains(@itemprop,"name")]//text()').extract(),
        'text': response.selector.xpath('//p[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you see in the browser is not exactly the same as parsed by `Scrapy` (and you should always expect this to be the case). The "genre" is located under a different parent and can be reached directly:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="genre"]/text()').extract_first()
Out[1]: u'Sports'
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Tricky! Thanks.

Comment: @EvanZamir yeah, note the `.selector` is unnecessary - `response` exposes the inner selector's methods..

Comment: Ah, even better. Thanks again.

Comment: Note also that contains() represents a substring relationship: "nana" is a substring of "banana". For the relationship between a node and its value, just use "=".